# Installing Dream textures dependency failed: OSError [ERRNO 30]

Tags: installation, dependencies, blender, add-on

I have encountered a problem in installing Dream textures in Blender. After installing the addon, you need to install a dependency. But after clicking installing the depency, it returns error, with last line as:

```
 File "/snap/blender/2790/3.3/python/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py", line 2195, in makefile
    with bltn_open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/snap/blender/2790/3.3/python/include/python3.10/pystate.h'
```

Does anyone have any idea, how to solve this problem?

What I have already tried:

1. Since it seems like, python-script didn't work because the file is read-only. I removed all the permissions of the directory. But then appears that you cannot remove the permissions, even as a root user.
2. Using chown to change directory owner. After that tried to remove the permissions. But still not allowed to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

start blender with admin rights (sudo) from the console. Install the plugin and dependencies.

Quit blender and start as normal user.

S.